# Why is my sucessful run mapreduce job not showing up in the resource manager web interface(0.0.0.0:8088) as an entry?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

Hello I have finished my hadoop cluster installation/configuration. I have run a couple mapreduce tests which are successfully giving back results.  However when I try to keep track of them on the resource manager web interface(0.0.0.0:8088) nothing comes up.

I have checked each log and everything seems fine.

here is the hadoop job running below, and an image of the web interface.

```
hadoop@rai-lab-hdwk-01:~$ yarn jar /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.2.4.jar pi 16 1000
Number of Maps  = 16
Samples per Map = 1000
Wrote input for Map #0
Wrote input for Map #1
Wrote input for Map #2
Wrote input for Map #3
Wrote input for Map #4
Wrote input for Map #5
Wrote input for Map #6
Wrote input for Map #7
Wrote input for Map #8
Wrote input for Map #9
Wrote input for Map #10
Wrote input for Map #11
Wrote input for Map #12
Wrote input for Map #13
Wrote input for Map #14
Wrote input for Map #15
Starting Job
2023-07-24 16:05:38,030 INFO impl.MetricsConfig: Loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2023-07-24 16:05:38,112 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled Metric snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2023-07-24 16:05:38,112 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: JobTracker metrics system started
2023-07-24 16:05:38,245 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 16
2023-07-24 16:05:38,255 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:16
2023-07-24 16:05:38,367 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_local1819974892_0001
2023-07-24 16:05:38,367 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Executing with tokens: []
2023-07-24 16:05:38,476 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://localhost:8080/
2023-07-24 16:05:38,477 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_local1819974892_0001
2023-07-24 16:05:38,479 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter set in config null
2023-07-24 16:05:38,488 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 2
2023-07-24 16:05:38,488 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: FileOutputCommitter skip cleanup _temporary folders under output directory:false, ignore cleanup failures: false
2023-07-24 16:05:38,488 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter
2023-07-24 16:05:38,531 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for map tasks
2023-07-24 16:05:38,532 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local1819974892_0001_m_000000_0
2023-07-24 16:05:38,559 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 2
2023-07-24 16:05:38,560 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: FileOutputCommitter skip cleanup _temporary folders under output directory:false, ignore cleanup failures: false
2023-07-24 16:05:38,580 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
2023-07-24 16:05:38,583 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: hdfs://10.4.5.242:9000/user/hadoop/QuasiMonteCarlo_1690214736371_1624327287/in/part0:0+118
2023-07-24 16:05:38,711 INFO mapred.MapTask: (EQUATOR) 0 kvi 26214396(104857584)
2023-07-24 16:05:38,711 INFO mapred.MapTask: mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb: 100
2023-07-24 16:05:38,712 INFO mapred.MapTask: soft limit at 83886080
2023-07-24 16:05:38,712 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufvoid = 104857600
2023-07-24 16:05:38,712 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396; length = 6553600
2023-07-24 16:05:38,717 INFO mapred.MapTask: Map output collector class = org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
2023-07-24 16:05:38,770 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner:
2023-07-24 16:05:38,772 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
2023-07-24 16:05:38,772 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output
2023-07-24 16:05:38,772 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufend = 18; bufvoid = 104857600
2023-07-24 16:05:38,772 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396(104857584); kvend = 26214392(104857568); length = 5/6553600
2023-07-24 16:05:38,780 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 0
2023-07-24 16:05:38,791 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local1819974892_0001_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of committing
2023-07-24 16:05:38,794 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Generated 1000 samples.
2023-07-24 16:05:38,794 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local1819974892_0001_m_000000_0' done.
2023-07-24 16:05:38,803 INFO mapred.Task: Final Counters for attempt_local1819974892_0001_m_000000_0: Counters: 23
        File System Counters
                FILE: Number of bytes read=319766
                FILE: Number of bytes written=876110
                FILE: Number of read operations=0
                FILE: Number of large read operations=0
                FILE: Number of write operations=0
                HDFS: Number of bytes read=118
                HDFS: Number of bytes written=1888
                HDFS: Number of read operations=7
                HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
                HDFS: Number of write operations=18
                HDFS: Number of bytes read erasure-coded=0
        Map-Reduce Framework
                Map input records=1
                Map output records=2
                Map output bytes=18
                Map output materialized bytes=28
                Input split bytes=149
                Combine input records=0
                Spilled Records=2
                Failed Shuffles=0
                Merged Map outputs=0
                GC time elapsed (ms)=0
                Total committed heap usage (bytes)=348127232
        File Input Format Counters
                Bytes Read=118
2023-07-24 16:05:38,803 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Finishing task: attempt_local1819974892_0001_m_000000_0
2023-07-24 16:05:38,804 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local1819974892_0001_m_000001_0
2023-07-24 16:05:38,805 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 2
2023-07-24 16:05:38,805 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: FileOutputCommitter skip cleanup _temporary folders under output directory:false, ignore cleanup failures: false
2023-07-24 16:05:38,805 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
2023-07-24 16:05:38,807 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: hdfs://10.4.5.242:9000/user/hadoop/QuasiMonteCarlo_1690214736371_1624327287/in/part1:0+118
2023-07-24 16:05:38,915 INFO mapred.MapTask: (EQUATOR) 0 kvi 26214396(104857584)
2023-07-24 16:05:38,916 INFO mapred.MapTask: mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb: 100
2023-07-24 16:05:38,916 INFO mapred.MapTask: soft limit at 83886080
2023-07-24 16:05:38,916 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufvoid = 104857600
2023-07-24 16:05:38,916 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396; length = 6553600
2023-07-24 16:05:38,916 INFO mapred.MapTask: Map output collector class = org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
2023-07-24 16:05:38,923 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner:
2023-07-24 16:05:38,923 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
2023-07-24 16:05:38,923 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output
2023-07-24 16:05:38,923 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufend = 18; bufvoid = 104857600
2023-07-24 16:05:38,923 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396(104857584); kvend = 26214392(104857568); length = 5/6553600
2023-07-24 16:05:38,925 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 0
2023-07-24 16:05:38,927 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local1819974892_0001_m_000001_0 is done. And is in the process of committing
2023-07-24 16:05:38,930 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Generated 1000 samples.
2023-07-24 16:05:38,930 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local1819974892_0001_m_000001_0' done.
2023-07-24 16:05:38,930 INFO mapred.Task: Final Counters for attempt_local1819974892_0001_m_000001_0: Counters: 23
 


..... 


Too long to post it all


.....
  
    
        File System Counters
                FILE: Number of bytes read=341805
                FILE: Number of bytes written=877010
                FILE: Number of read operations=0
                FILE: Number of large read operations=0
                FILE: Number of write operations=0
                HDFS: Number of bytes read=1888
                HDFS: Number of bytes written=1888
                HDFS: Number of read operations=52
                HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
                HDFS: Number of write operations=18
                HDFS: Number of bytes read erasure-coded=0
        Map-Reduce Framework
                Map input records=1
                Map output records=2
                Map output bytes=18
                Map output materialized bytes=28
                Input split bytes=149
                Combine input records=0
                Spilled Records=2
                Failed Shuffles=0
                Merged Map outputs=0
                GC time elapsed (ms)=0
                Total committed heap usage (bytes)=1898971136
        File Input Format Counters
                Bytes Read=118
2023-07-24 16:05:40,647 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Finishing task: attempt_local1819974892_0001_m_000015_0
2023-07-24 16:05:40,647 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map task executor complete.
2023-07-24 16:05:40,650 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for reduce tasks
2023-07-24 16:05:40,650 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local1819974892_0001_r_000000_0
2023-07-24 16:05:40,659 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 2
2023-07-24 16:05:40,659 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: FileOutputCommitter skip cleanup _temporary folders under output directory:false, ignore cleanup failures: false
2023-07-24 16:05:40,664 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
2023-07-24 16:05:40,668 INFO mapred.ReduceTask: Using ShuffleConsumerPlugin: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle@5c25a9e6
2023-07-24 16:05:40,670 WARN impl.MetricsSystemImpl: JobTracker metrics system already initialized!
2023-07-24 16:05:40,690 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: MergerManager: memoryLimit=2610115328, maxSingleShuffleLimit=652528832, mergeThreshold=1722676224, ioSortFactor=10, memToMemMergeOutputsThreshold=10
2023-07-24 16:05:40,692 INFO reduce.EventFetcher: attempt_local1819974892_0001_r_000000_0 Thread started: EventFetcher for fetching Map Completion Events
2023-07-24 16:05:40,724 INFO reduce.LocalFetcher: localfetcher#1 about to shuffle output of map attempt_local1819974892_0001_m_000005_0 decomp: 24 len: 28 to MEMORY
2023-07-24 16:05:40,727 INFO reduce.InMemoryMapOutput: Read 24 bytes from map-output for attempt_local1819974892_0001_m_000005_0
2023-07-24 16:05:40,727 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: closeInMemoryFile -> map-output of size: 24, inMemoryMapOutputs.size() -> 1, commitMemory -> 0, usedMemory ->24
2023-07-24 16:05:40,729 WARN io.ReadaheadPool: Failed readahead on ifile
EBADF: Bad file descriptor
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.posix_fadvise(Native Method)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.posixFadviseIfPossible(NativeIO.java:419)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX$CacheManipulator.posixFadviseIfPossible(NativeIO.java:296)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.ReadaheadPool$ReadaheadRequestImpl.run(ReadaheadPool.java:220)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
2023-07-24 16:05:40,730 INFO reduce.LocalFetcher: localfetcher#1 about to shuffle output of map attempt_local1819974892_0001_m_000012_0 decomp: 24 len: 28 to MEMORY
2023-07-24 16:05:40,732 INFO reduce.InMemoryMapOutput: Read 24 bytes from map-output for attempt_local1819974892_0001_m_000012_0
2023-07-24 16:05:40,732 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: closeInMemoryFile -> map-output of size: 24, inMemoryMapOutputs.size() -> 2, commitMemory -> 24, usedMemory ->48
2023-07-24 16:05:40,733 INFO reduce.LocalFetcher: localfetcher#1 about to shuffle output of map attempt_local1819974892_0001_m_000006_0 decomp: 24 len: 28 to MEMORY
2023-07-24 16:05:40,734 INFO reduce.InMemoryMapOutput: Read 24 bytes from map-output for attempt_local1819974892_0001_m_000006_0
2023-07-24 16:05:40,734 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: closeInMemoryFile -> map-output of size: 24, inMemoryMapOutputs.size() -> 3, commitMemory -> 48, usedMemory ->72
2023-07-24 16:05:40,736 INFO reduce.LocalFetcher: localfetcher#1 about to shuffle output of map attempt_local1819974892_0001_m_000000_0 decomp: 24 len: 28 to MEMORY
2023-07-24 16:05:40,737 INFO reduce.InMemoryMapOutput: Read 24 bytes from map-output for attempt_local1819974892_0001_m_000000_0
2023-07-24 16:05:40,737 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: closeInMemoryFile -> map-output of size: 24, inMemoryMapOutputs.size() -> 4, commitMemory -> 72, usedMemory ->96
2023-07-24 16:05:40,739 INFO reduce.LocalFetcher: localfetcher#1 about to shuffle output of map attempt_local1819974892_0001_m_000013_0 decomp: 24 len: 28 to MEMORY
2023-07-24 16:05:40,740 INFO reduce.InMemoryMapOutput: Read 24 bytes from map-output for attempt_local1819974892_0001_m_000013_0
2023-07-24 16:05:40,740 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: closeInMemoryFile -> map-output of size: 24, inMemoryMapOutputs.size() -> 5, commitMemory -> 96, usedMemory ->120
2023-07-24 16:05:40,741 INFO reduce.LocalFetcher: localfetcher#1 about to shuffle output of map attempt_local1819974892_0001_m_000007_0 decomp: 24 len: 28 to MEMORY
2023-07-24 16:05:40,742 INFO reduce.InMemoryMapOutput: Read 24 bytes from map-output for attempt_local1819974892_0001_m_000007_0
2023-07-24 16:05:40,742 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: closeInMemoryFile -> map-output of size: 24, inMemoryMapOutputs.size() -> 6, commitMemory -> 120, usedMemory ->144
2023-07-24 16:05:40,744 INFO reduce.LocalFetcher: localfetcher#1 about to shuffle output of map attempt_local1819974892_0001_m_000001_0 decomp: 24 len: 28 to MEMORY
2023-07-24 16:05:40,744 INFO reduce.InMemoryMapOutput: Read 24 bytes from map-output for attempt_local1819974892_0001_m_000001_0
2023-07-24 16:05:40,745 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: closeInMemoryFile -> map-output of size: 24, inMemoryMapOutputs.size() -> 7, commitMemory -> 144, usedMemory ->168
2023-07-24 16:05:40,746 INFO reduce.LocalFetcher: localfetcher#1 about to shuffle output of map attempt_local1819974892_0001_m_000014_0 decomp: 24 len: 28 to MEMORY
2023-07-24 16:05:40,747 INFO reduce.InMemoryMapOutput: Read 24 bytes from map-output for attempt_local1819974892_0001_m_000014_0
2023-07-24 16:05:40,747 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: closeInMemoryFile -> map-output of size: 24, inMemoryMapOutputs.size() -> 8, commitMemory -> 168, usedMemory ->192
2023-07-24 16:05:40,749 INFO reduce.LocalFetcher: localfetcher#1 about to shuffle output of map attempt_local1819974892_0001_m_000008_0 decomp: 24 len: 28 to MEMORY
2023-07-24 16:05:40,750 INFO reduce.InMemoryMapOutput: Read 24 bytes from map-output for attempt_local1819974892_0001_m_000008_0
2023-07-24 16:05:40,750 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: closeInMemoryFile -> map-output of size: 24, inMemoryMapOutputs.size() -> 9, commitMemory -> 192, usedMemory ->216
2023-07-24 16:05:40,752 INFO reduce.LocalFetcher: localfetcher#1 about to shuffle output of map attempt_local1819974892_0001_m_000002_0 decomp: 24 len: 28 to MEMORY
2023-07-24 16:05:40,752 INFO reduce.InMemoryMapOutput: Read 24 bytes from map-output for attempt_local1819974892_0001_m_000002_0
2023-07-24 16:05:40,753 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: closeInMemoryFile -> map-output of size: 24, inMemoryMapOutputs.size() -> 10, commitMemory -> 216, usedMemory ->240
2023-07-24 16:05:40,754 INFO reduce.LocalFetcher: localfetcher#1 about to shuffle output of map attempt_local1819974892_0001_m_000015_0 decomp: 24 len: 28 to MEMORY
2023-07-24 16:05:40,755 INFO reduce.InMemoryMapOutput: Read 24 bytes from map-output for attempt_local1819974892_0001_m_000015_0
2023-07-24 16:05:40,755 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: closeInMemoryFile -> map-output of size: 24, inMemoryMapOutputs.size() -> 11, commitMemory -> 240, usedMemory ->264
2023-07-24 16:05:40,756 INFO reduce.LocalFetcher: localfetcher#1 about to shuffle output of map attempt_local1819974892_0001_m_000009_0 decomp: 24 len: 28 to MEMORY
2023-07-24 16:05:40,757 INFO reduce.InMemoryMapOutput: Read 24 bytes from map-output for attempt_local1819974892_0001_m_000009_0
2023-07-24 16:05:40,757 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: closeInMemoryFile -> map-output of size: 24, inMemoryMapOutputs.size() -> 12, commitMemory -> 264, usedMemory ->288
2023-07-24 16:05:40,762 INFO reduce.LocalFetcher: localfetcher#1 about to shuffle output of map attempt_local1819974892_0001_m_000003_0 decomp: 24 len: 28 to MEMORY
2023-07-24 16:05:40,762 INFO reduce.InMemoryMapOutput: Read 24 bytes from map-output for attempt_local1819974892_0001_m_000003_0
2023-07-24 16:05:40,762 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: closeInMemoryFile -> map-output of size: 24, inMemoryMapOutputs.size() -> 13, commitMemory -> 288, usedMemory ->312
2023-07-24 16:05:40,764 INFO reduce.LocalFetcher: localfetcher#1 about to shuffle output of map attempt_local1819974892_0001_m_000010_0 decomp: 24 len: 28 to MEMORY
2023-07-24 16:05:40,764 INFO reduce.InMemoryMapOutput: Read 24 bytes from map-output for attempt_local1819974892_0001_m_000010_0
2023-07-24 16:05:40,764 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: closeInMemoryFile -> map-output of size: 24, inMemoryMapOutputs.size() -> 14, commitMemory -> 312, usedMemory ->336
2023-07-24 16:05:40,765 INFO reduce.LocalFetcher: localfetcher#1 about to shuffle output of map attempt_local1819974892_0001_m_000004_0 decomp: 24 len: 28 to MEMORY
2023-07-24 16:05:40,766 INFO reduce.InMemoryMapOutput: Read 24 bytes from map-output for attempt_local1819974892_0001_m_000004_0
2023-07-24 16:05:40,766 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: closeInMemoryFile -> map-output of size: 24, inMemoryMapOutputs.size() -> 15, commitMemory -> 336, usedMemory ->360
2023-07-24 16:05:40,767 INFO reduce.LocalFetcher: localfetcher#1 about to shuffle output of map attempt_local1819974892_0001_m_000011_0 decomp: 24 len: 28 to MEMORY
2023-07-24 16:05:40,768 INFO reduce.InMemoryMapOutput: Read 24 bytes from map-output for attempt_local1819974892_0001_m_000011_0
2023-07-24 16:05:40,768 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: closeInMemoryFile -> map-output of size: 24, inMemoryMapOutputs.size() -> 16, commitMemory -> 360, usedMemory ->384
2023-07-24 16:05:40,768 INFO reduce.EventFetcher: EventFetcher is interrupted.. Returning
2023-07-24 16:05:40,769 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 16 / 16 copied.
2023-07-24 16:05:40,770 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: finalMerge called with 16 in-memory map-outputs and 0 on-disk map-outputs
2023-07-24 16:05:40,777 INFO mapred.Merger: Merging 16 sorted segments
2023-07-24 16:05:40,777 INFO mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 16 segments left of total size: 336 bytes
2023-07-24 16:05:40,779 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: Merged 16 segments, 384 bytes to disk to satisfy reduce memory limit
2023-07-24 16:05:40,779 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: Merging 1 files, 358 bytes from disk
2023-07-24 16:05:40,780 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: Merging 0 segments, 0 bytes from memory into reduce
2023-07-24 16:05:40,780 INFO mapred.Merger: Merging 1 sorted segments
2023-07-24 16:05:40,780 INFO mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 1 segments left of total size: 351 bytes
2023-07-24 16:05:40,780 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 16 / 16 copied.
2023-07-24 16:05:40,786 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.skip.on is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.skiprecords
2023-07-24 16:05:40,839 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local1819974892_0001_r_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of committing
2023-07-24 16:05:40,841 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 16 / 16 copied.
2023-07-24 16:05:40,841 INFO mapred.Task: Task attempt_local1819974892_0001_r_000000_0 is allowed to commit now
2023-07-24 16:05:40,853 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: Saved output of task 'attempt_local1819974892_0001_r_000000_0' to hdfs://10.4.5.242:9000/user/hadoop/QuasiMonteCarlo_1690214736371_1624327287/out
2023-07-24 16:05:40,854 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce > reduce
2023-07-24 16:05:40,854 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local1819974892_0001_r_000000_0' done.
2023-07-24 16:05:40,854 INFO mapred.Task: Final Counters for attempt_local1819974892_0001_r_000000_0: Counters: 30
        File System Counters
                FILE: Number of bytes read=343123
                FILE: Number of bytes written=877368
                FILE: Number of read operations=0
                FILE: Number of large read operations=0
                FILE: Number of write operations=0
                HDFS: Number of bytes read=1888
                HDFS: Number of bytes written=2103
                HDFS: Number of read operations=57
                HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
                HDFS: Number of write operations=21
                HDFS: Number of bytes read erasure-coded=0
        Map-Reduce Framework
                Combine input records=0
                Combine output records=0
                Reduce input groups=2
                Reduce shuffle bytes=448
                Reduce input records=32
                Reduce output records=0
                Spilled Records=32
                Shuffled Maps =16
                Failed Shuffles=0
                Merged Map outputs=16
                GC time elapsed (ms)=0
                Total committed heap usage (bytes)=1898971136
        Shuffle Errors
                BAD_ID=0
                CONNECTION=0
                IO_ERROR=0
                WRONG_LENGTH=0
                WRONG_MAP=0
                WRONG_REDUCE=0
        File Output Format Counters
                Bytes Written=97
2023-07-24 16:05:40,860 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Finishing task: attempt_local1819974892_0001_r_000000_0
2023-07-24 16:05:40,860 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce task executor complete.
2023-07-24 16:05:41,483 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
2023-07-24 16:05:41,484 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local1819974892_0001 completed successfully
2023-07-24 16:05:41,501 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 36
        File System Counters
                FILE: Number of bytes read=5678187
                FILE: Number of bytes written=14902328
                FILE: Number of read operations=0
                FILE: Number of large read operations=0
                FILE: Number of write operations=0
                HDFS: Number of bytes read=17936
                HDFS: Number of bytes written=32311
                HDFS: Number of read operations=529
                HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
                HDFS: Number of write operations=309
                HDFS: Number of bytes read erasure-coded=0
        Map-Reduce Framework
                Map input records=16
                Map output records=32
                Map output bytes=288
                Map output materialized bytes=448
                Input split bytes=2390
                Combine input records=0
                Combine output records=0
                Reduce input groups=2
                Reduce shuffle bytes=448
                Reduce input records=32
                Reduce output records=0
                Spilled Records=64
                Shuffled Maps =16
                Failed Shuffles=0
                Merged Map outputs=16
                GC time elapsed (ms)=12
                Total committed heap usage (bytes)=19696451584
        Shuffle Errors
                BAD_ID=0
                CONNECTION=0
                IO_ERROR=0
                WRONG_LENGTH=0
                WRONG_MAP=0
                WRONG_REDUCE=0
        File Input Format Counters
                Bytes Read=1888
        File Output Format Counters
                Bytes Written=97
Job Finished in 3.559 seconds
Estimated value of Pi is 3.14250000000000000000
```

Here is a picture of the [resource manager web interface 8088](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VA5v8.png)

[About - resource manager web interface 8088](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7VcO.png)

[namenode yarn-site.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHAWR.png)

[datanode yarn-site.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QUgn.png)

I have tried to check the logs but they are fine. I expect the mapreduce job to show as an entry on the resource manager web interface.

Comment: If you click `FINISHED`, still nothing? What if you run the Mapreduce History Server?

Comment: Still nothing from FINISHED. Mapreduce History Server, do you configure that on mapred-site.xml and then run $HADOOP_HOME/bin/mapred --daemon start historyserver ?

Comment: Those steps look correct to me... I haven't personally had to configure Hadoop in years

Comment: Can you click about? Because if you install your resourcemanager as a ha then maybe your tasks go to master rm

Comment: @OneCricketeer I have just configured it and ran mapreduce jobs and no, it doesnt show anything from Map reduce History Server. I also tried using YARN command and nothing showed up yarn application -list.

Comment: @CompEng I have edited and added about page to the post. Could it be that? Because the application status is not showing up from anywhere. Not History server not Yarn command line (yarn application -list)

Comment: Can you share yarn site xml

Comment: @CompEng I have just edited the post with the yarn-site.xml image files.

Comment: So what is your hostname in datanode yarn site . Is it same with you looking at and you can define yarn site same all on your cluster and you can look this https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceModel.html